# How to assign function to global variable in javascript node.js?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, variables

How can I assign function to global variable in javascript node.js?
This function is for loading data from xml. And I want to use this data as a array but my `globalDataxml` is undefinded.

Code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

function loadXml(cb)
        {
            fs.readFile('data-xml/test_data.xml', function (err, data)
            {
                parseString(data, function (err, result)
                {
                    cb(result.xml.record);
                });
            });
        }

        var globalDataxml = loadXml(function (yourRecods) {
            return yourRecods;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just asign your variable like this :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

function loadXml(cb) {
    fs.readFile('data-xml/test_data.xml', function(err, data) {
        parseString(data, function(err, result) {
            cb(result.xml.record);
        });
    });
}
var globalDataxml = null;
loadXml(function(yourRecods) {
    globalDataxml = yourRecods;
});
```

You can't the way yuou do because fs.readFile is async.

## Warning

This way will not work if you want to use your variable after (always because of the async)

## Better way to do it :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

function loadXml() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile('data-xml/test_data.xml', function(err, data) {
          if(err)return reject(err);
          parseString(data, function(err, result) {
            if(err)return reject(err);
            resolve(result.xml.record);
          });
      });
    });
}
loadXml().then(globalDataxml => {
  //do what you want with it
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```